# WindowManager$BadTokenException on toast and activity change

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, android-activity, android-toast

I am showing a toast for already processed items from my utils file.

The scenario I am facing is that if I scan 10 items, and I change my screen, the toasts are still in process and my app crashes with

`Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@321daf0 is not valid; is your activity running?`

Below is the code that I am using.

**In Activity**

```
UtilityMethods.showToast(ActivityName.this, "message"));
```

**In UtilityMethods**

```
public static void showToast(Context c, String s) {
    Toast.makeText(c, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**What I tried**

I tried adding a try catch block like this:

```
public static void showToast(Context c, String s) {
    try {
        Toast.makeText(c, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (WindowManager.BadTokenException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it is still crashing.

The full exception is below:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@321daf0 is not valid; is your activity running?
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:720)
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
   at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:459)
   at android.widget.Toast$TN$2.handleMessage(Toast.java:342)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

I also found some other solutions on SO but it did not work.

Please suggest what can be done in my case, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's stating the issue ...`is your activity running?` so make sure what it's asking

Comment: I know the issue, I just don't know how to fix it. I have already mentioned what I tried. :(

Comment: Where in the activity do you call that `showToast` method?

Comment: don't use toasts to display data to user, use notifications instead. toasts will crash your app if you try and display a lot consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

You are using only `this` to point to your activity. Make sure `this` refers to your activity context and not anything else as Toast needs information from the Activity context. Try referring your activity with full name when you are using its context, Try using below code.

```
UtilityMethods.showToast(YourActivityName.this, "message"));
```

Comment: I have used ActivityName.this only, but it doesn't work. I have updated the question.